# How to change your data to be homoscedastic?

Tags: r, variance, heteroscedasticity

I want to use a linear discriminant analysis and need homoscedasticity. I'm wondering how to get this assumption correct with the data that I have. I have in total over 7000 samples, but I'm representing only 1000 in this example. The code is provided below. I know that normalization can make the data homoscedastic, but it's not working using a Box-Cox normalization. Do you have an idea to make this homoscedastic?

```
library(car)
gr = structure(c(3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 
6L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 
3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 
3L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
6L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
6L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("cra", 
"fo", "fu", "ma", "pa", "sc"), class = "factor")

    trait.norm = c(0.539897055670507, 0.540454903978601, 0.539926045117757, 0.540367038133052, 
0.539947627630311, 0.540410196539773, 0.539848460660358, 0.539963535844022, 
0.540075709527688, 0.539880143216218, 0.540155015974637, 0.539963535844022, 
0.539177785559091, 0.539783893265781, 0.539252813794612, 0.539952956612666, 
0.539974011257808, 0.540045761334772, 0.5392845214837, 0.539915091380691, 
0.539138881746003, 0.539369463066397, 0.539337368325491, 0.539388385638013, 
0.540187083139538, 0.539604634222916, 0.539439674320883, 0.539846999325865, 
0.540055442146469, 0.539093956244991, 0.539218095393896, 0.539417334682478, 
0.539439674320883, 0.539755775711974, 0.539741465781021, 0.53996485091991, 
0.539854287356619, 0.53895410136766, 0.539713966997019, 0.539259664197582, 
0.539516115236536, 0.539566631337142, 0.539261940844094, 0.539423462357384, 
0.53924593255126, 0.53996747621612, 0.539766789148679, 0.540115041013308, 
0.539189749493527, 0.539747846703874, 0.539277782577372, 0.53923207679029, 
0.53960641663402, 0.539199255426499, 0.539950295420346, 0.540043326600536, 
0.539369463066397, 0.53979465059037, 0.539881562403947, 0.539433616625335, 
0.53954067537286, 0.539354573097581, 0.539168148613569, 0.540178639291483, 
0.539881562403947, 0.539335203504991, 0.539081253242914, 0.539417334682478, 
0.539814370903614, 0.539699155326332, 0.539613521902141, 0.539531282004994, 
0.53979158706291, 0.539827830565501, 0.539868724724285, 0.539211057100744, 
0.539923316941418, 0.53963460612851, 0.539785436036832, 0.540086274777055, 
0.539692515009539, 0.539479402625015, 0.539435638751368, 0.539722119328304, 
0.539369463066397, 0.539776149146102, 0.539651915167273, 0.539467602682177, 
0.539627616365144, 0.53994092914481, 0.540331296440948, 0.539577601893347, 
0.539915091380691, 0.540059048641616, 0.539433616625335, 0.539615292147616, 
0.53963111600647, 0.539882979796678, 0.539384201976604, 0.53962586296378, 
0.539516115236536, 0.539419380180238, 0.539602849365139, 0.539239020279607, 
0.539601062056149, 0.539311179080548, 0.539573955155222, 0.539546280008566, 
0.539833762747538, 0.539788515554438, 0.540388081164903, 0.540509922336169, 
0.539755775711974, 0.53975735526472, 0.539617059973441, 0.540321437190868, 
0.539592088583317, 0.539786976798539, 0.540456425764473, 0.539977913053268, 
0.539516115236536, 0.53954067537286, 0.539453708232778, 0.539358842910274, 
0.539620588383994, 0.539184974833523, 0.540529431296056, 0.539481359535384, 
0.539878722230418, 0.5395830531429, 0.539561111775017, 0.540218073021122, 
0.539536925896651, 0.5397156018014, 0.539744660450588, 0.539562954181314, 
0.539718864895188, 0.539898453519215, 0.539942272168512, 0.53985573938632, 
0.539042544972448, 0.539500777126806, 0.539555569185049, 0.540429340599416, 
0.540289274112402, 0.539485265049661, 0.539895656060175, 0.538967801272533, 
0.540436398338744, 0.53969583960888, 0.540325933153247, 0.539857189564677, 
0.540341919878401, 0.539259664197582, 0.540279856932846, 0.539899849609291, 
0.539473515217217, 0.539702462193929, 0.539096485035693, 0.539575779784592, 
0.539771478334222, 0.539685839036317, 0.539726984807067, 0.540130785832232, 
0.540393874798123, 0.540122945564793, 0.53959388821686, 0.540397166441028, 
0.539311179080548, 0.539104047936483, 0.539573955155222, 0.538923573218813, 
0.539668991399397, 0.539158452656641, 0.539005586560204, 0.538768609972895, 
0.539491102634203, 0.539512296874073, 0.539699155326332, 0.539836717425254, 
0.539728602336517, 0.539609974134316, 0.539421422736636, 0.539579421486191, 
0.539707405971567, 0.539806825448195, 0.539726984807067, 0.539411180483681, 
0.539597480066309, 0.539704112319003, 0.539835241034755, 0.539730217723971, 
0.539858637894878, 0.539862971828323, 0.539592088583317, 0.539852833472377, 
0.539867289242482, 0.539931481092623, 0.539802274675523, 0.539192131389025, 
0.539736657930329, 0.539319960315374, 0.539519922890414, 0.539451711970668, 
0.539350290782401, 0.539870158383191, 0.539682487597632, 0.539352433505891, 
0.539601062056149, 0.539846999325865, 0.539575779784592, 0.539447710886098, 
0.539496915520658, 0.539604634222916, 0.53962586296378, 0.539994656097892, 
0.539579421486191, 0.539733442088209, 0.53979465059037, 0.539670686381221, 
0.539479402625015, 0.539400864121163, 0.539627616365144, 0.53943765798135, 
0.539632862255212, 0.53960819660298, 0.539602849365139, 0.539013574988662, 
0.539459679964298, 0.539039931985246, 0.53985573938632, 0.540548411571057, 
0.539136418450069, 0.540018654329983, 0.539498847685412, 0.539747846703874, 
0.539632862255212, 0.539330864312211, 0.539845536120752, 0.539808338446716, 
0.53937368950683, 0.539917840096016, 0.539180185631804, 0.539386295324659, 
0.539579421486191, 0.539636347630728, 0.539481359535384, 0.53979158706291, 
0.539337368325491, 0.539817375457444, 0.539229755323652, 0.539461664874759, 
0.539487213664152, 0.539498847685412, 0.539129005798137, 0.539864412797645, 
0.53985573938632, 0.539663892722005, 0.539156019389642, 0.539830800469768, 
0.539615292147616, 0.539733442088209, 0.540006092763334, 0.53973505107263, 
0.540295805087822, 0.539651915167273, 0.539812865713143, 0.539864412797645, 
0.540088607370767, 0.539912335772615, 0.539651915167273, 0.539786976798539, 
0.539680808501022, 0.539101530873254, 0.539369463066397, 0.539946291254241, 
0.539175381828459, 0.539411180483681, 0.540159355650743, 0.539076144331367, 
0.539577601893347, 0.539477442938749, 0.539453708232778, 0.539653633196535, 
0.539892851542622, 0.539870158383191, 0.539337368325491, 0.540323238485504, 
0.539288997420033, 0.539189749493527, 0.539999754538218, 0.539954284741571, 
0.539491102634203, 0.539677443532806, 0.539561111775017, 0.540305967859459, 
0.539273273226908, 0.539604634222916, 0.53959388821686, 0.539609974134316, 
0.539680808501022, 0.539827830565501, 0.540354142743902, 0.539675757652988, 
0.53960641663402, 0.539662188571644, 0.539398791891739, 0.540214001513954, 
0.539398791891739, 0.539776149146102, 0.539380006152553, 0.53960641663402, 
0.540466242411462, 0.539324331548514, 0.53983966452924, 0.539668991399397, 
0.540079243799403, 0.540387250028018, 0.539604634222916, 0.539525614381265, 
0.53959388821686, 0.539282278521867, 0.539339529970481, 0.539257384145093, 
0.539151141668521, 0.539870158383191, 0.539815874150585, 0.539878722230418, 
0.539803793566037, 0.539687511386549, 0.539720493192387, 0.539803793566037, 
0.539575779784592, 0.540232179999618, 0.53973183097326, 0.540349798379516, 
0.54040289383866, 0.540243109951338, 0.540348054139555, 0.539638086766221, 
0.539363100269756, 0.539629367377909, 0.540444936441627, 0.539677443532806, 
0.539494980627347, 0.539382105587893, 0.539682487597632, 0.539670686381221, 
0.540395522339951, 0.539720493192387, 0.539429563662642, 0.539153582396174, 
0.539138881746003, 0.539201622913927, 0.539592088583317, 0.539502703850024, 
0.540497092374904, 0.53929568645619, 0.539352433505891, 0.539148697198947, 
0.539808338446716, 0.539396716663049, 0.54048109524052, 0.539461664874759, 
0.539177785559091, 0.539985673711287, 0.539908189385422, 0.539498847685412, 
0.539559266810078, 0.540022393222659, 0.540086274777055, 0.539234394767107, 
0.540034758834807, 0.539984384226022, 0.539736657930329, 0.539435638751368, 
0.540158272605324, 0.539857189564677, 0.539592088583317, 0.539546280008566, 
0.539743064169716, 0.539924681881051, 0.540415027213936, 0.540289274112402, 
0.540372986199582, 0.540431700437809, 0.540271292609704, 0.540434053007511, 
0.53975261036872, 0.539286761114194, 0.540044544697753, 0.53979465059037, 
0.539491102634203, 0.539880143216218, 0.539597480066309, 0.540313283026994, 
0.540471475017672, 0.540483297483593, 0.539453708232778, 0.539762081491665, 
0.539206347145291, 0.539702462193929, 0.539566631337142, 0.540304129119631, 
0.539572128000523, 0.540455665258419, 0.540210935814601, 0.539689181496128, 
0.539639823539333, 0.539348144920913, 0.539557419281694, 0.539477442938749, 
0.539280032221997, 0.539330864312211, 0.539824853008182, 0.539500777126806, 
0.539291230407882, 0.539802274675523, 0.539192131389025, 0.539846999325865, 
0.539304559028361, 0.53959388821686, 0.539754194081206, 0.539431591597636, 
0.539720493192387, 0.539830800469768, 0.539751024570813, 0.539905416442968, 
0.539557419281694, 0.539790052308055, 0.539308975657407, 0.539931481092623, 
0.539622348977626, 0.539910955376492, 0.539705760243562, 0.539081253242914, 
0.539868724724285, 0.540027357373932, 0.540001025270336, 0.539749436683771, 
0.53937368950683, 0.539797706164815, 0.539116575022588, 0.53984113524928, 
0.539536925896651, 0.539743064169716, 0.539487213664152, 0.539751024570813, 
0.539643290015741, 0.539738262665103, 0.539579421486191, 0.539586674792124, 
0.539326512341495, 0.53920398681775, 0.539557419281694, 0.539785436036832, 
0.5392845214837, 0.539820372264349, 0.539790052308055, 0.539453708232778, 
0.539439674320883, 0.538822751077337, 0.539239020279607, 0.538981392503711, 
0.539590286471092, 0.539720493192387, 0.539101530873254, 0.539315576176567, 
0.537882234892825, 0.539288997420033, 0.538962334417011, 0.539076144331367, 
0.539496915520658, 0.53960819660298, 0.539481359535384, 0.53969583960888, 
0.539958259292192, 0.539390472922609, 0.540439514239153, 0.539417334682478, 
0.539817375457444, 0.539239020279607, 0.539475480471262, 0.539402933357173, 
0.539568466096225, 0.53878985598762, 0.539477442938749, 0.539433616625335, 
0.539439674320883, 0.539782348481843, 0.54016259731972, 0.540363619404988, 
0.540173322570939, 0.54048109524052, 0.539404999605612, 0.539722119328304, 
0.539337368325491, 0.539842604085707, 0.539820372264349, 0.539830800469768, 
0.539590286471092, 0.5397156018014, 0.53920398681775, 0.539651915167273, 
0.539687511386549, 0.539717234432823, 0.539986961619561, 0.539423462357384, 
0.539881562403947, 0.539417334682478, 0.539106561106889, 0.53962586296378, 
0.539487213664152, 0.539360973143596, 0.539417334682478, 0.539718864895188, 
0.5397792528611, 0.539894254685216, 0.539814370903614, 0.53984113524928, 
0.539679127147447, 0.539493043000269, 0.53979158706291, 0.539806825448195, 
0.539356709563653, 0.539613521902141, 0.539743064169716, 0.539508467762284, 
0.539356709563653, 0.539811358575774, 0.539899849609291, 0.540006092763334, 
0.539148697198947, 0.539388385638013, 0.539865851934649, 0.539573955155222, 
0.539923316941418, 0.539508467762284, 0.539845536120752, 0.539489159523913, 
0.539192131389025, 0.539411180483681, 0.539564794033762, 0.539857189564677, 
0.539851377730394, 0.539398791891739, 0.540554403271917, 0.539496915520658, 
0.539177785559091, 0.539411180483681, 0.539880143216218, 0.540420625178248, 
0.539862971828323, 0.539854287356619, 0.539124044981025, 0.53920398681775, 
0.539356709563653, 0.53951802039951, 0.539367345225058, 0.539451711970668, 
0.539818874827573, 0.53973183097326, 0.539304559028361, 0.539672379081329, 
0.539447710886098, 0.539335203504991, 0.539441687775557, 0.539469576328043, 
0.539156019389642, 0.539919211876174, 0.539525614381265, 0.539830800469768, 
0.539124044981025, 0.539485265049661, 0.53966048211868, 0.539525614381265, 
0.539797706164815, 0.539467602682177, 0.53979158706291, 0.539694178421454, 
0.539286761114194, 0.538795881296761, 0.53920398681775, 0.539286761114194, 
0.539407062872304, 0.539493043000269, 0.539689181496128, 0.53960641663402, 
0.539867289242482, 0.539433616625335, 0.539341688446249, 0.539641557954398, 
0.540305967859459, 0.53951802039951, 0.539550003437221, 0.539489159523913, 
0.539086346286525, 0.53942549904818, 0.53905554866285, 0.539413234839947, 
0.539411180483681, 0.539636347630728, 0.539045153865079, 0.539493043000269, 
0.540029830476916, 0.53969583960888, 0.539814370903614, 0.53973505107263, 
0.539717234432823, 0.539717234432823, 0.53942549904818, 0.539467602682177, 
0.53975735526472, 0.5396672941317, 0.539622348977626, 0.539629367377909, 
0.53966048211868, 0.539564794033762, 0.539531282004994, 0.539400864121163, 
0.539755775711974, 0.539386295324659, 0.539489159523913, 0.539618825384081, 
0.539653633196535, 0.53954067537286, 0.539029438916591, 0.539465626228277, 
0.539725365131782, 0.539514207396419, 0.539032068369202, 0.539496915520658, 
0.539402933357173, 0.53958848187557, 0.539950295420346, 0.539433616625335, 
0.539650194810026, 0.539548143019148, 0.539380006152553, 0.539324331548514, 
0.539319960315374, 0.539824853008182, 0.539862971828323, 0.539343843759074, 
0.539584865216116, 0.539815874150585, 0.539449712856943, 0.539099009909048, 
0.539815874150585, 0.539566631337142, 0.539377903664599, 0.539377903664599, 
0.539796179369974, 0.539675757652988, 0.539845536120752, 0.539709049506974, 
0.539639823539333, 0.53962586296378, 0.539860084380104, 0.539820372264349, 
0.539241327829407, 0.539360973143596, 0.539504627860239, 0.539354573097581, 
0.539710690853729, 0.539392557184374, 0.540337510053423, 0.539697498575836, 
0.539449712856943, 0.539449712856943, 0.53929346008439, 0.539220434416554, 
0.539356709563653, 0.539180185631804, 0.539561111775017, 0.540042107040749, 
0.539322147541941, 0.539657062288112, 0.540188133215917, 0.540313283026994, 
0.540003562098856, 0.539453708232778, 0.539749436683771, 0.539728602336517, 
0.539380006152553, 0.539259664197582, 0.539404999605612, 0.539371577824967, 
0.539297909529897, 0.540423011929656, 0.539151141668521, 0.539875874852279, 
0.539675757652988, 0.539308975657407, 0.53973183097326, 0.540101338732108, 
0.539947627630311, 0.539494980627347, 0.539653633196535, 0.539533165932469, 
0.539755775711974, 0.539192131389025, 0.539330864312211, 0.53969583960888, 
0.539435638751368, 0.53927552958126, 0.539288997420033, 0.539333035502672, 
0.539042544972448, 0.53954067537286, 0.539481359535384, 0.539306768975517, 
0.539930124638985, 0.54040289383866, 0.53969583960888, 0.539382105587893, 
0.539356709563653, 0.53976365276912, 0.539467602682177, 0.539160882204867, 
0.539848460660358, 0.539431591597636, 0.539180185631804, 0.539546280008566, 
0.53960819660298, 0.539651915167273, 0.539463646960943, 0.539854287356619, 
0.539473515217217, 0.539579421486191, 0.539170563363265, 0.539680808501022, 
0.539369463066397, 0.539894254685216, 0.539617059973441, 0.539315576176567, 
0.5397156018014, 0.539341688446249, 0.539921950295984, 0.539227430360091, 
0.539827830565501, 0.539880143216218, 0.539199255426499, 0.539710690853729, 
0.539702462193929, 0.539475480471262, 0.539550003437221, 0.539402933357173, 
0.539725365131782, 0.538989495562951, 0.539261940844094, 0.53975261036872, 
0.539895656060175, 0.540062642247457, 0.539773037308223, 0.539280032221997, 
0.539239020279607, 0.539951626839841, 0.539311179080548, 0.539512296874073, 
0.539461664874759, 0.539498847685412, 0.539577601893347, 0.539948962351423, 
0.539317769862394, 0.53991646659849, 0.539845536120752, 0.539553716515315, 
0.53952182271431, 0.540334852792603, 0.539409123163061, 0.539264214091501, 
0.539288997420033, 0.539311179080548, 0.539071019485001, 0.539803793566037, 
0.539315576176567, 0.539679127147447, 0.53950654916261, 0.539897055670507, 
0.539595685376326, 0.539514207396419, 0.539932835857623, 0.539712330015768, 
0.539326512341495, 0.538912337754692, 0.539815874150585, 0.539613521902141, 
0.539562954181314, 0.539449712856943, 0.539713966997019, 0.539032068369202, 
0.539288997420033, 0.539453708232778, 0.539160882204867, 0.539358842910274, 
0.539071019485001, 0.539648472120529, 0.539730217723971, 0.53984992012746, 
0.539148697198947, 0.539765221986908, 0.539760508150891, 0.539584865216116, 
0.539871590222326, 0.539846999325865, 0.539317769862394, 0.539768354258069, 
0.539311179080548, 0.539948962351423, 0.539680808501022, 0.538846304658684, 
0.53975261036872, 0.539427532814709, 0.539917840096016, 0.53979465059037, 
0.539979210462756, 0.540249015471143, 0.539402933357173, 0.540039663523971, 
0.539758932743133, 0.539658773358908, 0.539986961619561, 0.53979158706291, 
0.539776149146102, 0.539747846703874, 0.540042107040749, 0.538783810761405, 
0.539704112319003, 0.539211057100744, 0.539158452656641, 0.539650194810026, 
0.539641557954398, 0.539034693692346, 0.539322147541941, 0.53944570605261, 
0.53951802039951, 0.539531282004994, 0.538973250740441, 0.540016154184038, 
0.539920581941865, 0.539684164441369, 0.539441687775557, 0.539636347630728, 
0.539904027357592, 0.539833762747538, 0.539491102634203, 0.539636347630728, 
0.539785436036832, 0.53950654916261, 0.539627616365144, 0.540412615634996, 
0.53931337925144, 0.539319960315374, 0.5397792528611, 0.539538801943279, 
0.539264214091501, 0.539921950295984, 0.539239020279607, 0.540429340599416, 
0.539928766493864, 0.539803793566037, 0.539404999605612, 0.53887243749529, 
0.539725365131782, 0.53911906885042, 0.539449712856943, 0.539694178421454, 
0.540310547274624, 0.539579421486191, 0.539180185631804, 0.539870158383191, 
0.540270335770011, 0.539797706164815, 0.539646747094507, 0.539823361351297, 
0.540414224187483, 0.54032772476539, 0.539915091380691, 0.539604634222916, 
0.539220434416554, 0.539407062872304, 0.539662188571644, 0.539620588383994, 
0.539411180483681, 0.53975735526472, 0.539114077342375, 0.539820372264349, 
0.539266483946658, 0.539689181496128, 0.53932868992727, 0.54000987724669, 
0.539101530873254, 0.539723743306814, 0.53957029831577, 0.5397792528611, 
0.539820372264349, 0.539754194081206, 0.53957029831577, 0.53976365276912, 
0.539553716515315, 0.539592088583317, 0.53917297443237, 0.539665594573962, 
0.539141341261031, 0.539910955376492, 0.540063837262537, 0.539655348902066, 
0.539227430360091, 0.539086346286525, 0.539984384226022, 0.539165730175685, 
0.539812865713143, 0.539423462357384, 0.539392557184374, 0.540381407571828, 
0.539785436036832, 0.539182582054115, 0.539684164441369, 0.539291230407882, 
0.539467602682177, 0.53957029831577, 0.540013647974332, 0.539782348481843, 
0.539865851934649, 0.539457692224119, 0.539648472120529, 0.539398791891739, 
0.539093956244991, 0.539645019727676, 0.539806825448195, 0.539358842910274, 
0.539136418450069, 0.539443698350945, 0.539356709563653, 0.539875874852279, 
0.539239020279607, 0.539268750416401, 0.539771478334222, 0.539330864312211, 
0.539923316941418, 0.538926370810586, 0.539335203504991, 0.539088886878657, 
0.539146248979695, 0.53960641663402, 0.539469576328043, 0.539865851934649, 
0.539126527299784, 0.53954441440059, 0.539725365131782, 0.539677443532806, 
0.539483313675167, 0.539252813794612, 0.53973183097326, 0.539632862255212, 
0.539713966997019, 0.539622348977626, 0.539071019485001, 0.538929163912215, 
0.539457692224119, 0.539257384145093, 0.539266483946658, 0.539138881746003, 
0.539390472922609, 0.539343843759074, 0.539277782577372, 0.539326512341495, 
0.539111575801736, 0.539131480484025, 0.539595685376326, 0.539371577824967, 
0.539421422736636, 0.539277782577372, 0.539106561106889, 0.539371577824967, 
0.539257384145093, 0.539427532814709, 0.539151141668521, 0.539447710886098, 
0.5392845214837, 0.539324331548514, 0.539529395440631, 0.539335203504991, 
0.539352433505891, 0.53920398681775, 0.539643290015741, 0.539846999325865, 
0.53984992012746, 0.539899849609291, 0.54037129124018, 0.539431591597636, 
0.539225101892484, 0.53937368950683, 0.540016154184038, 0.539699155326332, 
0.539799230978373, 0.539477442938749, 0.539136418450069, 0.539473515217217
)

leveneTest(trait.norm ~gr)
# Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = median)
#        Df F value Pr(>F)    
# group   5     4.9  2e-04 ***
# 994
```

[image: boxplot]